# Java vs Python on Google Apps Engine

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, real-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing Java vs Python on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085898/choosing-java-vs-python-on-google-app-engine)

What is more comfortable way of creating and deploying app for GAE?
I am trying to create a web service and after some reasearch I decided that Google App Engine could be a good fit. I did a little bit of programming in Java as well as Python, but I am not a pro in either of them. That is why I am deciding whether to use one or another.

Comment: @Michael: True, although the answer there is more than two years old and is predicated on the claim that the Python API is more mature than the Java one, which is a time-specific claim.

Comment: Also duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105832/google-app-engine-java-or-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799811/google-appengine-java-or-python which are more recent, and others.

Comment: @agf: Fair enough, if there's a **recent** one. Most recent I'm seeing is still 18 months back, which again, seems a long time in this realm, but there may well be three more people who think that's good enough, which is fine. :-)

Comment: But all of them are over a year old!!! The service has changed a lot since then. Java wasn't very stable back then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use whichever you prefer, it's pretty much a subjective decision.

It used to be that the Python API was more complete and robust, since it was first, but I don't think that's true any longer.

Comment: What about frameworks compatible with GAE offered for these languages? And what about possible portability of a code from GAE to other services? Cause I already know that if you use Django, porting application to other service is pretty easy, but are there any similar frameworks for Java as well?

Comment: @Blackie: Java has a **huge** ecosystem and probably dozens of frameworks you can choose from. :-) You can go the full [JavaEE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html) route, or "just" the [servlets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html) part of it, or use [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) (with JavaEE or separately), or [Play](http://www.playframework.org/) for that agile, light-weight approach, or any of really quite a few others. Keep your core code encapsulated and you can move around as you see fit.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, thank you for the tips for frameworks. Gonna look them up and compare with Django and Web.py and will choose the easiest and fastest one. I wanna deploy the whole application as fast as possible.

Comment: @Blackie: Glad that helped. Don't limit yourself to the links above, that really just scratches the surface. Have fun,

Comment: I really like Play Framework for Java, think I am gonna try it!