# Google App Engine Go-Python/Java hybrid application

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, go, hybrid

Can one write a hybrid Go-Python/Java application and run it on Google App Engine as one application, or do they need to be split into two apps and communicate with each other through HTTP calls? Is there any tutorial or example on something like this being done?

Comment: Very similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342059/can-i-write-parts-of-the-google-app-engine-code-in-java-other-parts-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494539/java-and-python-together-in-single-google-app-engine-project

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's a recipe for a lot of communication overhead, deployment trouble, and extra effort in general.

Comment: @NickJohnson - Go is still experimental, so some functionality is not available in it yet. If it wasn't for that, I'd go with pure Go.

Comment: @ThePiachu If you need features not available in Go, your best option for now is probably to not use Go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can deploy several "versions" of the same application at once. Each version will be accessible using a fully qualified URL, and they can all be in different languages.

Comment: Why use versions for this? Why not go with two different apps? whats the advantage of use versions over different apps?

Comment: Two different apps cannot share a datastore.

Comment: And I think it's against the GAE Terms of Service to use several apps working together as a single app, see Section 4.3e of the TOS: http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html

Comment: @Arief __or otherwise access the Service in a manner intended to avoid incurring fees__ since having two versions running at the same time will not give you double free quote I thinks its ok. A nightmare to manage but doable.

Comment: @ShayErlichmen: Yes, that section also covers any other attempt to exploit the free quota, and I think what the asker had in mind (two separate apps that communicate with each other) could unintentionally give him/her double free quota and thus break the TOS on that particular section. Especially since the alternative of deploying the "hybrid" app as different versions exists.