# Help me decide what to use with Google App Engine for this practical work

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I'm working on a practical work for college, and I have to develop a web-app that could be used by all the teachers from my province.

The application should let the users (teachers) manage some information related to their daily duties. One of the requirements is that I must use 
Google App Engine platform for developing and hosting the web application.

I have 2 months to finish the work.

I have some intermediate knowledge of C++, so what language (Python or Java ) and web framework do you think would the best to 
develop the application in less time?

I know this is not a strictly programming questions, but please don't delete this post at least until I get a 
few answer in order to have an idea of how to proceed.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: read the hello world documentation of the both languages, and pick the language you feel its easy to build with it.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085898/choosing-java-vs-python-on-google-app-engine.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using Python + Django framework. I love Java, but for the Google App Engine there is much more documentation online for Python.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at Java + [slim3](http://sites.google.com/site/slim3appengine/). I have my own MVC framework for AppEngine (PhD thesis work), and I really wish I had started after slim3 came out. I'd be using it myself. I can't really speak vs using Python on AppEngine, but I don't think I'd recommend any other Java framework vs slim3. I've tried a few. As an example, I use Struts2 at work. I would not recommend Struts2 given your timeframe -- the learning curve would make your deadline ambitious. Part of this is just due to the fact that Struts2 isn't quite a full stack (saving data in AppEngine is a big deal when you are first learning), which makes only some documentation useful for your particular project. Slim3 sidesteps this by being explicitly targeted to AppEngine.

Comment: thanks ccoakley...but is there documentation enough about slim3? I just made a quick Google search but didn't find many examples

Comment: Did you follow the link in my post? I found the getting started guide + the documentation section to be quite helpful. Since almost everything is POJO, there isn't much to document. But you can answer the question best yourself. If there isn't enough documentation there for you, the answer is "no." On the other hand, most other java web frameworks have a greater learning curve (plus the additional complications caused by the AppEngine datastore api).

Answer (score 0):

Go with python and default webapp framework . As you are new to both java and python. Appengine on python has been there for sometime, you will find lots of solution on python as it was introduced earlier. Learning curve is very small in python when compared to java according to me.  Also go for eclipse with [pydev plugin](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) as your IDE. This will make your deployment and development much easier . [Google 's own documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/) is the best place to start.

All you need to do is spend some time reading the whole documentation patiently . Even i started with appengine very recently.