# Language using the most of the Api of google

Tags: google-api, cloud

I would like to develop à cloud application collect all the API of google ( spreadsheet, d'oc, drive , maps , G+, hangout, youtube...) 
what is the better way ,and the better language to develop a cloud application using all the Api of google
Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to develop a web application that uses a lot of Google API's is to use [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/). That way, your code runs on Google's server infrastructure, close to the servers that offer the API's you mention.

On GAE, you can take your pick between Python, Java, PHP or Go, whichever you prefer. I like the Python environment best, but both the Python and Java environments are stable and well-supported. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085898/choosing-java-vs-python-on-google-app-engine) for more information).

However, in a more general sense, you should base your decision on which environment, language and tools to use on what you're familiar and comfortable with.

Comment: I'm fluid in google Apps script , and i think that i can use the most API of google , but i'm scared if it is the best decision for a great cloud application or no ?

Comment: Google Apps Script has nothing at all to do with Google App Engine.